# Synonymise [home] and [domestic-hacks]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

As all the questions there should be about [life hacks](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/what-is-a-lifehack),  -hacks postfix seems to be useless, as pointed in [this question](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74/tags-should-not-contain-the-words-lifehacks-or-hacks).

So there is no need to separate [domestic-hacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domestic-hacks) and [home](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home) questions.

Maybe [domestic-hacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domestic-hacks) should become the synonym of [home](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home)?

Comment: I recommend retagging "domestic-hacks" questions to "home" and see if they repop before synonyming them.

Comment: I have retagged them all to [tag:home]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag doesn't need a synonym because we don't need the tag. Just burninate the [domestic-hacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domestic-hacks) tag.

Tags shouldn't be so broad that we can use them to divide all the questions on the site into two sections, which is what that tag aims to do.

Comment: Burninate is a moderator action that prevents anyone from ever using the tag in future. Is that what you meant to suggest?

Comment: @starsplusplus Yup. I'm strongly against it being used.

Comment: I don't mind the sentiment; I'm just questioning the necessity. It seems like an unlikely combination of words to come up in a more fully-fledged site, that's all. (I suspect the reason we have 20 questions tagged with it is because people saw other questions with the tag - which is only a problem in this muddled private beta stage.)

Comment: I have retagged them all to [tag:home]